# How to initialize a data property to a prop object property in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to initialize a data object from a prop object in my component.

My view which calls the component has something like this

```
<template>
  <Comp1 :item="itmObj" />
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "myView",
    data: function() {
      return {
        itmObj: {color: "red", size: "Medium", quantity: "10"}
      }
    }
  }
<script>
```

The component Comp1.vue has this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Initial Quantity  {{item.quantity}}</div>
    <div>Available Quantity  {{availableQuantity}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "comp1",
    props: ["item"]
    data: function() {
      return {
        availableQuantity: this.item.quantity
      }
    }
  }
<script>
```

I'm getting a blank availableQuantity.

Comment: This code is working for me. Did you check console and see any error there?

Comment: Do you import components automatically ? If not, you should import `Comp1` component to your parent component... Otherwise your code works for me

Comment: The console error said that the data was non reactive. I tried setting the availableQuantity to blank and using different life cycle hooks. The availableQuantity still does not show. But if I do some code changes and save (to force refresh the NPM server), the availableQuantity appears

Comment: @AhmetZeybek yes, the component was import using import Comp1 from "@/components/Comp1.vue";

Comment: Can you post full code of both components?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the beforeCreate hook to set the availableQuantity. The adjusted code looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Initial Quantity  {{item.quantity}}</div>
    <div>Available Quantity  {{availableQuantity}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: "comp1",
    props: ["item"]
    data: function() {
      return {
        availableQuantity: 0
      }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
      this.availableQuantity = this.item.quantity;
    }
  }
<script>
```